# Can you make a board like Intel Edison?

Tags: cpu

I have a project to design a new board to be used in specific application. The boards would control and take image from CMOS camera under ground. Because of limitation in power consumption and cost (more than 1,000 boards would be produced), it is fascinating to use the cpu and RAM in the intel's edison board. It has incredibly low power consumption and large storage, but I can't just use it because it's too expensive for my project.

Is it possible to buy just the cpu, RAM and build similar board?

Comment: would be difficult, its not as easy as building an arduino. I'm guessing you would need extensive knowledge of computer architecture. How about using the raspberry pi?

Comment: @Sada93, knowledge of computer architecture won't help. You need an NDA with Intel, and a volume of 1000 a week to get any real support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly.  There is a lot of stuff crammed on that board, though.  It's probably at least a 6 layer board.  It would be a complex board to design and a bit costly to produce, but it is certainly possible.  It would be difficult to get the cost down to the same level as the Edison board itself.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I'd be satisfied with just that cpu and RAM. And I wonder if I can buy the cpu Z34XX just like STM32f4 ARM. Is it possible? Actually I don't need the stuffs like Wi-fi and USB and so on. Thus I'm interested in building an embedded system with Z34XX and Ram and the components totally different from the Edison board.

Comment: Well, that could certainly save on some of the complexity. I believe you can get the parts separately, though I don't know who carries them.

Comment: By my rough estimation, you could conceivably get 1000-off 6L, 80x100mm PCBs for ~£35 each. Parts and assembly are then likely to get you closer to £80 to £100 total. You could see prices drop even further at quantities of 10K. But this is now an EE project, requiring an external design company or in house experienced electronic design engineer. You need to look at design for mass production, supplier chains, design for test. It is not a hobby project.